# How do I access my nvm node version number from .bash_profile to customize my terminal prompt?

Tags: node.js, terminal, command-prompt, bash, nvm

I want to customize my terminal prompt so that it displays whatever version of node that I'm using through nvm. So, for example, the terminal prompt my read:

```
[current directory] : [node version] $
```

Does anyone know how to modify .bash_profile to display the current nvm node version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` :

```
PS1='\w : $(node --version) \$'
```

or

```
PS1='\w : $(nvm run node --version) \$'
```

Comment: If you change your node version using nvm your prompt does not update. Other than that it does work.

Comment: @tilted did you by any chance find the solution for this?

Comment: Replace `node --version` with `nvm run node --version`.

Comment: @BohdanKhodakivskyi I did not. It looks like saruftw stepped up to the plate. I just tested his solution and it appears to be working perfectly. Appreciate you saruftwn. Thanks for reminding me to circle back around to this bodan :).

Comment: Unfortunately, @saruftw solution doesn't appear to be working to me, it prints out the same version after `nvm use`. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`:

```
nvm=$([[ $NVM_BIN =~ ([^/]+)/bin$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" || echo "system")
PS1="($nvm) $PS1"
```

This is much faster than running `nvm` directly. For timings and `zsh`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53039288/5353461).