# How do I find the currently activated version with nvm?

Tags: nvm

I use `nvm` and want to find out which version of node is currently running.

If the `system` version is being used, I want to see the string `system`.

Ideally, I'm looking for a string to put in my prompt.

Answer (score 12):

run this in terminal

```
nvm current
```

or

```
node -v
```

`nvm ls`

for list all version

```
nvm use version_name
```

for use that version

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`:

```
[[ $NVM_BIN =~ ([^/]+)/bin$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" || echo "system"
```

For `zsh`, first do:

```
setopt BASH_REMATCH
```

---

This is much faster than using `nvm current`, especially for use in a prompt:

```
$ time nvm current
system

real    0m0.188s
user    0m0.149s
sys     0m0.042s
```

Compared with:

```
$ time [[ $NVM_BIN =~ ([^/]+)/bin$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" || echo "system"

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.007s
system
```

Almost 0.2 seconds vs only 0.009 seconds.